# Is there anyway to change font-size of all text with a specific font-size?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

This question has been bugging me lately. I've developed a site in regular CSS a couple years ago, and now I came back and wanted to change some font sizes etc. I know CSS variables are the ideal solution to this one but is there any other way to change font-size of text with specific font-size? For example, all p, h1, h2, h3, h4 etc. with font sizes of 14px should be converted to 16px.

Comment: depends on how the font-size of 14px is set for those p, h1, h2, h3, h4

Comment: @JaromandaX, this is also what I'm thinking. the font-sizes are static sizes to each class, converting it to variables seems like a long process.

Comment: right ... you know how CSS works? if you have `.x { font-size: 14px }` and later you have `.x { font-size: 16px}` the latter "wins" ... or you can play with specificity

Comment: why not use the `em` and `rem` units, which are made for this purpose?

Comment: Honestly different font classes have different sizes. You would have to guess/check at that point, unless there was a doc for the font that has px sizes

Comment: @JaromandaX yes I know this, but as I have said this is an old site being recovered. some of the css properties has !important so the "latter" isn't 100% effective, and changing it one by one is a hassle.

Comment: Well, there is no simple way then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right, you have your old css split between a lot of classes.
So instead of

```css
p{
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

you have

```css
.first {
    font-size: 14px;
}
//other stuff
.second {
    font-size: 14px;
}
//other stuff
.third {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

A good solution would be to use something like VS code's replace all function

[image]

Otherwise you can add !important if you are feeling lazy...

```css
.first {
    font-size: 14px;
}
//other stuff
.second {
    font-size: 14px;
}
//other stuff
.third {
    font-size: 14px;
}
// override all
p {
    font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

But using !important is highly not recommended for obvious reasons.
If the code is structured the way I understood playing with specificity will not work.
simply because here the second one does not override the first

```
//this is more specific
.some-container .some-div {
    font-size: 14px;
}
// this fails to override
p {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't thought of this one! probably because I'm using plain text editor. thanks for reminding this one!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this work for you but try this one !

```
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

or when you use bootstrap try below one

```
html {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
  html {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
  html {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
  }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
  html {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to set a font-size of 16px in the :root element in CSS, and replace all the font-size properties with rem units (there is a replace tool in VS Code to make this task easier). rem will look the font size of the root element, which in this case is 16px.

```
:root {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.example {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```